# Why does a similar rule in the ANTLR grammar file produce a completely different tree?

Tags: t-sql, parsing, antlr

I am using the grammar file at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql/TSqlParser.g4. It has a `built_in_functions` grammar rule. I want to parse a new function, DAYZ, as a built-in function. I introduced it thus in the .g4

```
built_in_functions
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx
    : BINARY_CHECKSUM '(' '*' ')'                       #BINARY_CHECKSUM
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx
    | DATEADD '(' datepart=ID ',' number=expression ',' date=expression ')'  #DATEADD
    | DAYZ  '(' date=expression ')'  #DAYZ
```

When I use grun to test the grammar, I get unexpected results for DAYZ. For a DATEDIFF I get what I expect.
[image]

For DAYZ, I get the following tree

[image]

Why does the parser not treat DAYZ as satisfying the rule `built_in_functions` like it does for DATEDIFF ? If the parser recognizes DAYZ eventually as an _Id, it should do the same for DATEDIFF. There must be something wrong in the way I am introducing DAYZ into the grammar but I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated. And apologies if I am not using the correct ANTLR terminology. I am a newbie to ANTLR.
I am using antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar

Comment: Where are you defining DAYZ in the lexer? For problems like this, you should print out the token stream.

Comment: I am defining DAYZ in the parser. And it seems to recognize it. Here is the token stream for DATEDIFF [@0,0:7='DATEDIFF',<'DATEDIFF'>,1:0]
[@1,8:8='(',<'('>,1:8]
[@2,9:11='DAY',<ID>,1:9]
[@3,12:12=',',<','>,1:12]
[@4,14:14='X',<ID>,1:14]
[@5,15:15=',',<','>,1:15]
[@6,16:16='Y',<ID>,1:16]
[@7,17:17=')',<')'>,1:17]
[@8,20:19='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0] and the token stream for DAYZ [@0,0:3='DAYZ',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='(',<'('>,1:4]
[@2,5:5='X',<ID>,1:5]
[@3,6:6=')',<')'>,1:6]
[@4,9:8='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]

Comment: It is not recognizing input `DAYZ` correctly: `DAYZ [@0,0:3='DAYZ',<ID>,1:0]`. The `<ID>` in that output means that it is being recognized as an ID. Add the rule `DAYZ: 'DAYZ';` to TSqlLexer.g4 with the other keywords--before the rule for ID that is near the bottom of the file. Then, make sure to do a clean build: remove *.tokens and *.interp so you don't pick up ghost definitions somehow.

Comment: Thanks Kaby76.  That worked.  When I did not have it in the LEXER, I did get a warning when compliling the PARSER  " implicit definition of token DAYZ in parser" . I assumed that it was okay. In this case did the implicit defintion  happen after the ID ?

Comment: With "implicit" token warnings, Antlr "defines" an integer for the token, and you can still try to parse, but the results might not be right. The warning means that there doesn't seem to be a rule for the token in the lexer grammar. As you found with your code, this should be an error. There was no rule `DAYZ: 'DAYZ';` in the *lexer* grammar TSqlLexer.g4, so the lexer would recognize the input `DAYZ` only as an `ID`. There are other implicit token warnings with the TSql split grammar, and I think I raised an Issue over in the grammars-v4 repo for this.

Comment: @Kaby76  One thing that I am noticing is that once I got the DAYZ working as a built-in function per yours and Mike Cargal's suggestion, I see that the DATEADD is no longer recognized as a built-in function when it is part of  DATEADD(DAYZ(X), Y,Z). it becomes recognized function_call (scalar_function_name (func_proc_name_server_database_schema (func_proc_name_database_schema (func_proc_name_schema (id_ (keyword DATEDIFF)))))) . Is this expected behavior ? I would assume that it should be still be recognized as a built_in function.

Comment: It is expected because by `DATEADD '(' datepart=ID ',' number=expression ',' date=expression ')'`, the first arg of dateadd() can only be an `ID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238280/discussion-between-qfirstlast-and-kaby76).

Answer (score 2):

Move your lexer rule for `DAYZ` to appear before the `ID` rule in the `TSqlLexer.g4` file.

since the `id_` rule recognizing the token, then it must be being tokenized as an ID token.  This will happen if you `DAYZ` rule definition is after the `ID` rule definition.

When ANTLR finds two lexer rules that match the same string of input characters (i.e. "DAYZ"), then it will use whichever rule appears first in the grammar.

Comment: I would like to combine your answer with Kaby76 comments. I hope that is okay. Kaby76 commented "Add the rule DAYZ: 'DAYZ'; to TSqlLexer.g4 with the other keywords--before the rule for ID that is near the bottom of the file. Then, make sure to do a clean build: remove *.tokens and *.interp so you don't pick up ghost definitions somehow. "